# Delegation and retrieving info on IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to get heading info from CLLocationManager but it's not getting called. I did everything as the documentation says, but something is very wrong.
I'm using locationManager delegating into my app delegate.

Here is the method to retrieve heading messages:

```
  - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    NSLog(@"%@", newHeading);
}
```

Here is the part from main()

```
  locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

But nothing happens! With debugging, NSLog is never getting called.
When I do same with     [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] everything works fine, shows the location info, using another method (very same looking but using

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

but I need heading info here.

Comment: did you check before that your device can retrieve heading info? you must check [CLLocationManager headingAvailable]==YES before. Also note that the simulator will always answer NO.

Comment: Don't be fooled by -headingAvailable - its deprecated in favor of using the class method referred to above +headingAvailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the deal.
Code is perfectly fine, the issue is in Iphone simulator.
Somehow it is providing location info just fine, but heading info is not provided thus the message is never sent.
Talk about weird things, apple.

Comment: Saved me a lot of hours of research. I couldn't see where I was going wrong.